# How to enable old ligatures, long s in LaTeX?

Tags: typography, ligatures

How would you enable quaints (old-style ligatures) in LaTeX? E.g. the st, ct, sp ligatures &c. Is there also a way to contextually put in the long s (`ſ`)? Keep in mind that Overleaf won't let me use the `fontspec` package.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Without fontspec and xetex, it seems hard to do.

Comment: you can use xetex and luatex (and so fontspec) on overleaf as far as I understand

Comment: Overleaf documentation on using xelatex: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/XeLaTeX

Comment: Which font do you use? Does this font have the old ligatures?

Comment: In LaTeX, you can load  kpfonts with the `oldstyle` option. See the manual here: http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/kpfonts/doc/kpfonts.pdf