# How can I produce the old glyph "long s" in Latex?

Tags: font-encodings

In old texts, one finds the glyph "long s", that I was
not able to find a proper Latex representation:
      https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_s

How can I produce "long s" in Latex?

I am aware of [How to enable old ligatures, long s in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485364/how-to-enable-old-ligatures-long-s-in-latex) but this was not helpful in solving the problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Answers to your question depend strongly on which TeX engine -- pdftex, xetex, luatex, something else? -- and which text font you employ. Please provide some more information.

Comment: I use pdflatex, but can run luatex if needed.

Comment: Use amsart standard fonts.

Comment: Computer Modern doesn't have that glyph, afaik. So you'd have to either change to a font which has (e.g., `kpfonts` or others) or import that single glyph from another font, which will give nonuniform looks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Computer Modern Unicode` does have the glyph, as well as a few other fonts, e.g.  `erewhon`, `libertinus`, &c. However, I found only `ebgaramond` that worked – yet it doesn't make the difference with the final `s` (I added a spelling error at the end of the first verse to check).

Here is illustrating example, with `CMU Serif`, `EB Garamond` and  the commercial font `Sabon Next LT Pro`, with fragments of a poem (in French) with an overabundance of `ss`. With `fontspec`, the option  to obtain the long `s` is  `StylisticSet=4` or `Style=Historic` (with possibly some more features)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newcommand{\lgS}{\char"017F}
\newcommand{\lgSS}{{\color{red}\char"017F\char"017F}}

\begin{document}

 \begin{verse}[1em]
 \setmainfont[Ligatures = Rare, Style=Historic]{Sabon Next LT Pro}%
\poemtitle{Complainte amoureuse}
 Ah! fallait-il que je vous visses, \\
 Fallait-il que vous me plussiez, \\
 Qu’ingénument je vous le disse, \\
 Qu’avec orgueil vous vous tussiez !
   \end{verse}

\setmainfont[Ligatures = Rare, Style=Historic, StylisticSet =4]{CMU Serif}%
    \begin{verse}[1em]
 Fallait-il que je vous aimasse,\\
 Que vous me désespérassiez,\\
 Et qu’en vain je m’opiniâtrasse,\\
 Et que je vous idolâtrasse\\
 Pour que vous m’a\lgSS a\lgSS ina\lgSS iez !
   \end{verse}

\setmainfont[Ligatures = Rare, Style=Historic]{EB Garamond}%
\begin{verse}[1em]
 Fallait-il que je vous aimasses,\\
 Que vous me désespérassiez,\\
 Et qu’en vain je m’opiniâtrasse,\\
 Et que je vous idolâtrasse\\
 Pour que vous m’a\lgSS a\lgSS ina\lgSS iez !
 \end{verse}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Just out of curiosity: Is this your own poetry? :-)

Comment: @Mico: Not at all. It is from one of the greatest French humorists of  the end of the 19th century, Alphonse Allais, who used in this poem a plethora of rarely used past tenses (even then). Here's a link to the poem, in case you read French: [Complainte amoureuse](https://poesie.webnet.fr/lesgrandsclassiques/Poemes/alphonse_allais/complainte_amoureuse).

Comment: Many thanks, this is great! Et oui, en tant que Suisse (du canton Valais), je sais bien lire -- et parler! -- en français.

Comment: Is the long s at the end of "vous" correct?  In German or English, the usual round s would be used in that position.  (My command of French fails when it comes to traditional typographic conventions.)

Comment: Luatex returns this when I compile your file:   !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "Sabon Next LT Pro" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  
                                                  
l.12 ...s = Rare, Style=Historic]{Sabon Next LT Pro}
                                                  %
?

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Precisely, only the commercial font works correctly. It seems all features are not implemented, or not fully implemented in the .otf of ebgaramond, to say nothing of CM Unicode. I don't know whether there is a workaround with fontspec.

Comment: @User-JG: If you didn't buy it, that is normal. I added the example with this font to show how easy it is with fontspec, when all features are correctly implemented in the font. The other reason is that it is one of the most beautiful fonts I know.

Comment: @bernard  I just noticed now: here,  lualatex & xelatex  miss the first verse but correctly reproduce the last two verses. So, inserting  either the CMU Serif or EB Garamond commands in my text finally produced the long-s as desired !!  Thank you all for the great help!!  Would it be possible to make such glyphs standard in Latex, like ordinary coding for foreign letters?....

Comment: For CMU Serif, you obtained it via the macro I defined, not directly?

Comment: @Bernanrd  I happily used your macro.

Comment: Note that, for double long s, one should use some negative kerning to obtain something close to a ligature.

Answer (score 4):

Under both LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX, the character -- "LATIN SMALL LETTER LONG S" in Unicode parlance -- may be typeset by inputting `\char"0017F`.

[image]

The default font under both LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX is `Latin Modern`. To use a different Opentype font, be sure to load the `fontspec` package and issue suitable `\setmainfont` and `\setsansfont` directives.

```
%%% compile with either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}
\char"017F
\end{document}
```

Comment: OK, compiled with no problem. But, how to make long-s to appear in my text?  z.E. hier: Man sieht nun \"uberhaupt leicht, da\ss\ wie man auch ein
Zahlengeb\"aude annimmt, dasselbe deswegen angenommen werde, damit sich durch
wenige einfache Zeichen alle m\"ogliche ganze Zahlen vorstellen lassen, und
da\ss\ man dabey \"uberhaupt auf die Einf\"ormigkeit der characteristischen
Structur zu  zu sehen habe. "Dasselbe" sollte etwa  "daffelbe" sein.

Comment: @User-JG - Is something stopping you from writing `das\char"017Felbe`? (The first `s` should be an ordinary, i.e., short, "s", no?) Incidentally, why do you input `ä`, `ö`, `ü` and `ß` as `\"a`, `\"o`, `\"u` and `\ss`?

Comment: And you can define a shorthand if you find `\char"017F" to be too unreadable, e.g., `\newcommand\longs{\char"017F }`.

Comment: In both cases above, the long-s is not showing in my text. Nothing is showing when using the  \char"017F". My keyboard does not have the accents, I'm an old timer, don't know how to work around this. Easier to stick to old coding.

Comment: @user-JG — please tell me more about your TeX system setup.

Comment: @User-JG -- What version of LaTeX are you using?  This will be reported as the first line of your log file.  I'm not sure, but think that if you are using an older version, that may be affecting your results.  If the places where this character should appear in your text are just "closed up", you should also find messages in the log file about missing characters in the font being used; please report that information too.

Comment: This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (rev 5238)

Comment: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)

Comment: The only suspicious message is this one:   Package inputenc Warning: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.

Comment: @User-FG - Any chance you could update your TeX distribution?

Comment: @Mico I was under the impression that I have the latest TeX distribution.  Hot to check & update?

Comment: @User-JG - I'm not familiar with Debian, so I can't check what the very latest versions of TeXLive for Debian may be. Do check out the posting [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/5001) and especially [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/5001). If I understand the instructions at [TeX Live and Debian/Ubuntu](https://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html#vanilla) correctly, you should be able to get at least TeXLive2019 and maybe even TeXLive2020.

Comment: @Mico I have TeX Live 2015 and will try to install the 2019 version.

Comment: @Mico I failed upgrading, get the following persistent messages:    W: Target Packages (partner/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4

Comment: @User-JG - I'm afraid I am definitely out of my depth here. I don't know what to tell you, except to recommend that you post a new query in which you (a) describe your current computing setup -- both the OS and the TeX distribution -- (b) ask how to find out what the most recent version of TeXLive for Debian is, and (c) ask how you should go about upgrading to this most recent version.